# Can we burninate [tag:recommendations]?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [recommendations](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) tag seems to be rather popular, but I'm not sure what it is supposed to represent.

It seems to sometimes be used to indicate "I want people to recommend a book/video game/other product" (which is generally off topic anyway), and sometimes means "I am asking a question, and would like answers", which seems completely redundant.

Can we get rid of this tag?  Or is there a meaningful definition we could give it that would justify its existence on this site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, this tag needs to be removed.

I had no idea that it even existed, but I suspect that it will eventually reappear in new questions.

Just like we did for the now-removed "parenting" tag, we should review the questions that have the "recommendations" tag to see if the remaining tags are descriptive.